# Babylon JS NullEngine not a constructor

Tags: node.js, babylonjs

Using Babylon 4.2

```
import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs';
var engine = new BABYLON.NullEngine();
var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
```

Yields

`TypeError: BABYLON.NullEngine is not a constructor`

In Babylon 4.2.  However, the documentation uses this syntax : https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/classes/babylon.nullengine

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs';
```

to

```
import BABYLON from 'babylonjs';
```

Worked for me, when writing with Node.js v16